# Unable to install quantreg package and update R version

Tags: r, quantreg, installr

I am using R version 3.3.1 on RStudio interface, and a Windows 10 OS. I was trying to install the 'quantreg' package for quantile regression, however I was getting the error message

> Warning in install.packages : 
>    InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>     downloaded length 180224 != reported length 1521162
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘quantreg’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)

I repeated the process afterwards several times but got the last line of the above error all the time. Thinking it was due to using an older R version, I tried updating by installing the 'installr' package, but that too gave me the same error as above. I tried updating R from the Tools Menu, but it kept telling me that the current R version is the latest.
Also this is my first time here, so apologies if I've messed up the blockquoting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade R.

Download an older version [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/) (I recommend 3.2.5) and install.

Then (in R), go to Tools > Global Options > press the "Change" button.

Now simply select the version you want and restart R and try reinstalling the package.

Comment: I upgraded R to 3.3.3 (before seeing this) by uninstalling R and then downloading from CRAN and all the packages I wanted are being installed properly now. Thanks anyway!